# Failed to find valid MySQL data directory with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mysql

I forgot the password for the MySQL server on the Windows 10 and try to drop it.

I followed to the instructions at the official MySQL website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

1. I stopped the MySQL server in the task manager -> Services
2. I created the text file with the appropriate SQL query.
3. I tried to execute command this command but nothing not happens.

   ```
   mysqld --init-file=c:\1\new\np.txt
   ```
4. I tried to execute with `--console` parameter and got the following error:

   [image]
5. I try to execute `mysqld --console` without parameters and got the same error:

   [image]

I mean the `mysqld` command does not execute the parameters.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I went to the link YOU LISTED and clearly you did not follow all of the instructions.  `To have server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file, add the --console option to the mysqld command. ` .. I read that on the link you provided.  Please go back and follow that text completely.  Also, on windows.. you will run this as a service.  Ideally, you would have stopped the service, done the stuff it said, and restarted the service after seeing that `--console` worked.  Good luck.. Come back if you still aren't getting anywhere.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I updated question

Comment: PERFECT! (and bummer).. We could spend hours figuring this out but if it were me, I would uninstall and reinstall at this point since you are trashing any data anyways.